# How to use values generated from insert statements inside a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a process which requires that I insert new records to multiple tables and I thought I'd try using a stored procedure as I am developing in PHP 5.3.5 and using the MySql Server 5.5.8.

Created a simple Insert procedure but I wanted to obtain the value of the recently added id so that it could be used for a subsequent insert.

The id values of the table are set to auto_increment, and are bigint(20). The insert statement works, but when I try to use the DECLARE statement I obtain the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your >MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @i BIGINT(20); END' at line >8

THe stored procedure is as follows:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE test(
   IN a VARCHAR(255),
   IN b VARCHAR(255),
   IN c BIGINT(20)
)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tableA (datetime_created) VALUE (NOW());
   DECLARE @i BIGINT(20);   // or BIGINT(20);
   SET @i = SELECT id FROM tableA ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1;
   INSERT INTO tableB(attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4)  VALUES (a, b, c, @i);
END
```

I have removed all statements, and when I build what I would think is a simple stored procedure, the error appears as soon as the second line is added. Any help would be greatly appreciated for I have been searching and attempting to resolve this but I have not found a solution as of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. variable declarations should come first
2. using `DECLARE` you meant to use a [local (stored procedure level) variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-local-variable.html) instead of user variable. For that don't use `@` in front of a variable name.
3. there is a typo in first INSERT. It should be `VALUES` instead of `VALUE`
4. use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function to retrieve a value of an auto_incremented column for a row that has been just inserted instead of

Your code might look something like this

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test(
   IN a VARCHAR(255),
   IN b VARCHAR(255),
   IN c BIGINT(20)
)
BEGIN
   DECLARE i BIGINT(20);   // or BIGINT(20);

   INSERT INTO tableA (datetime_created) VALUES (NOW());
   SET i = LAST_INSERT_ID();
   INSERT INTO tableB(attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4)  VALUES (a, b, c, i);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

In this particular case you don't need a variable at all. A revised version of your SP might look like this

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test(
   IN a VARCHAR(255),
   IN b VARCHAR(255),
   IN c BIGINT(20)
)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tableA (datetime_created) VALUES (NOW());
   INSERT INTO tableB(attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4)  VALUES (a, b, c, LAST_INSERT_ID());
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1530/1)** demo for both versions

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I never included my delimiter in the original post. This LAST_INSERT_ID is that called with respect to the last query? Could the system ever pull another id from another table if another insert occurred?

Comment: You're welcome ;) `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is the only safe way to obtain the last auto generated value for auto_increment column in the most recent INSERT statement. [The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set delimiter to something else then `;`

As you are probably using phpMyAdmin, there's an input field for that under the main textarea. The standard is `;`, use eg `##` instead.

Comment: Yes sorry I never included my delimiters. I thought that was trivial to the issue that I was having since i was able to successfully insert records but I could not get the declare statement working.